# Limit question help please here?

Tags: limits

So I have to find the limit of $\frac 1 {1\times3} +\frac 1 {3\times5} + .. + \frac 1 {(2n-1)\times (2n+1)}$ as $n$ approaches infinity ... I don't know how to express the $\frac 1{1\times3} +\frac 1 {3\times5}$  part ?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** $$\dfrac1{(2n-1)(2n+1)} = \dfrac12 \left(\dfrac1{2n-1} - \dfrac1{2n+1} \right)$$ And use telescopic summation/cancellation.

Comment: the answer is zero then..but why,in my book it is 1/2 :/

Comment: Not $0$. **Almost** everything cancels. But look at the "left part" of the first term.

Answer (score 0):

We use partial fractions to evaluate the sum. $$S={\frac{1}{2}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left({\frac{1}{2i-1}} - {\frac{1}{2i+1}}\right)}$$ By cancelling terms we get $$S={\frac{2n}{4n+1}}$$ Now $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} S(n) = \frac{1}{2}$$